# How to call a class method without creating an instance

Tags: c++, oop

In `Java` you can call a **class method** without creating a variable with the instance of the class and still call that class method:

```
new Database().GetSomeValuesOutOfSomeTableJava();
```

If I try the same with `C++` I get an error:

```
new Database()->GetSomeValuesOutOfSomeTableCpp();
```

Am I doing it wrong? How can I achieve the same result?

Comment: C++ isn't Java. The whole object model is totally different.

Comment: `new Database().GetSomeValuesOutOfSomeTableJava();` *does* create a new instance of that class.

Comment: @KerrekSB Same story with `C#` and other programming languages

Comment: @Houssni: In C++, "class method" usually refers to a *static member function*, which you call without a state like `Database::GetSomeValues()`.

Comment: @Houssni Can you turn the method into a static member function? Otherwise, do you have to create it on the heap (using new)? Would `Database().GetSomeValuesOutOfSomeTableCpp();` be an option at the calling site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
new Database().GetSomeValuesOutOfSomeTableJava();
```

That *does* create an instance (note the `new`); it then abandons it for the garbage collector to clean up.

In C++, you can create a temporary object without `new`:

```
Database().GetSomeValuesOutOfSomeTableCpp();
```

This will do the same as the Java example, except that the temporary will be destroyed deterministically at the end of this statement.

Whether you *should* be creating temporaries like this is another matter.

Comment: You came up as first with this solution and this is what I was searching for, thank you

Answer (score 6):

You would do this:

```
(new Database())->GetSomeValuesOutOfSomeTableCpp();
```

But you'd be leaking memory, so that's a pretty bad idea. Also, note that that this (both in C++ and Java) *does* indeed create a new instance. It's just a new instance that's not stored in a variable.

A better version might be something like this:

```
{
    Database temporary;
    temporary.GetSomeValuesOutOfSomeTableCpp();
}
```

Using RAII to initialize and properly destroy the temporary, and scoping to ensure it doesn't exist for longer than you'd like it to and mess up any later scoping.

Alternatively, as pointed out by Mike Seymour, you could do:

```
Database().GetSomeValuesOutOfSomeTableCpp();
```

Which will also avoid the memory leak.

Comment: But at the same time that is absolutely, unforgivably terrible C++.

Comment: Yeah it creates a new instance only for that action to call the method and then it deallocates it, right?

Comment: @Houssni: Yes; but that's exactly what your Java does.

Comment: `Database().GetSomeValuesOutOfSomeTableCpp();` would do the same thing without the memory leak.

Comment: Unless you explicitly call `delete` in C++, you'll leak memory when you call `new`.

Comment: O my, so there are a ton of huge differences between java and c++.  One of them is that java has automatic garbage collection with allows you to new without a delete. C++ does not have automatic garbage collection.

Comment: `Database().GetSomeValuesOutOfSomeTableCpp();` THIS is what I was searching for

Comment: @Houssni: Doesn't do what? Both examples do exactly the same thing: create a instance and call a method on it. The difference is that Java has a garbage collector to tidy the mess up after you, while C++ will leak it if you use `new`.